# Unity: Applying MoveRotation to an object with an offset

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, quaternions

In a Unity VR app I'm building, I'm trying to rotate an object that is currently 'being held'. The technique I'm using is to find the desired rotation and feed it into the target objects Rigidbody via Rigidbody.MoveRotation. This works well when I use a test quaternion exposed in the inspector, but my quaternion math is completely failing me when it comes to finding the target rotation I want. I've got the position tracking working perfectly, it's just the rotation thats killing me!

The desired outcome is that the target object in question keeps its current rotation (from the moment its picked up) and simply applies the frame-by-frame difference of the VR controller. I thought this would be pretty straight forward, but I'm getting strange results. This is what I have so far:

```
public Rigidbody targetRigidbody;

public Quaternion controllerRotationSnapshot;
public Quaternion targetRotationSnapshot;

public float grabRadius = 0.25f;

public Collider[] grabResults;

Quaternion deltaRotation;

void Awake() {
    grabResults = new Collider[5];
}

// This is triggered externally
public void Pickup() {
    Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(transform.position, grabRadius, grabResults);

    for (int i = 0; i < grabResults.Length; i++) {
        if (grabResults[i] != null) {
            if (grabResults[i].CompareTag("Grabbable")) {
                targetRigidbody = grabResults[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                targetRotationSnapshot = targetRigidbody.transform.rotation;
                i = grabResults.Length;
            }
        }
    }

    controllerRotationSnapshot = transform.rotation;
}

public void LetGo() {
    if (!targetRigidbody) {
        return;
    }

    targetRigidbody = null;
    grabResults = new Collider[5];
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (!targetRigidbody) {
        return;
    }

    Quaternion deltaRotationDifference = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(controllerRotationSnapshot);

    targetRigidbody.MoveRotation(targetRotationSnapshot * deltaRotationDifference);
}
```

It works perfectly as long as the target object is at a rotation of 0,0,0 (in euler angles). But the moment the target object is picked up with a different rotation at all (i.e. [X: 20, Y: -5, Z: 325] or something), the frame-by-frame controller difference (a 'delta rotation' I've heard this called?) gets applied on a completely different axis. It's very confusing because as far as I can tell, nothing about my code is applied locally, it's all using global calculations?

I've done a lot of Googlin' and can't find an answer at all, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you considering pivot points?

Comment: The movement calculation allows for the picked up object to remain offset from the controller (no snapping or centering occurs, its supposed to remain exactly where it gets picked up local to the hand). Would that require an extra rotation to be factored in?

Comment: Why don't you just make the grabbed object a child of the "grabber" object when it gets grabbed?

Comment: Physics don't get applied correctly when an object is childed like that unfortunately